# File not found using lstinputlisting with variable as argument

Tags: listings, paths

Trying to create a new environment using `lstnewenvironment` to list code in a document. Sometimes the contents of this environment are typed directly in the tex file, sometimes they come from external files. I want the same environment to be able to handle both situations. This is the environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{output}[1][]
{
    \lstset{
        style=outputstyle,
        #1
    }
    \ifthenelse{\not\isempty{\fromfile}}
        {\lstinputlisting[style=outputstyle, #1]{example.cpp}\medskip}
        {NO FILE CONTENTS FOUND}
}{
    \endminipage
}
```

The environment works as expected if I type the filename directly in the environment definition (`example.cpp` above).

However, I want to pass the file name as an optional argument (hence the `ifthenelse`) to the environment, using a custom key. In the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\lst@Key{fromfile}{}{\def\fromfile{#1}}
\makeatother
```

and in the document:

```
\begin{output}[fromfile={example.cpp}]
\end{pfaoutput}
```

and to change the environment definition to:

```
    \ifthenelse{\not\isempty{\fromfile}}
        {\lstinputlisting[style=outputstyle, #1]{\fromfile}\medskip}
        {NO FILE CONTENTS FOUND}
```

However this does not work and produces a `File not found` error:

```
! Package Listings Error: File `chapters/chapter_5/code/example.cpp(.tex)' not found.
```

I've configured `\lstset{inputpath=chapters/chapter_5/code}` option, the file is found and renders correctly if I type its name directly, but does not if I pass it as an argument to the environment (although the path indicated by the error is correct). Do I need to process `\fromfile` in any way?

Comment: You probably need to expand `\fromfile` before `\lstinputlisting`. Try `\newcommand*{\myInputListing}[2]{\lstinputlisting[style=outputstyle, #2]{#1}}` and replace `\lstinputlisting[style=outputstyle, #1]{\fromfile}` with `\expandafter\myInputListing\expandafter{\fromfile}{#1}`. If this doesn't work, please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317) (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`); then, we can easily test candidate solutions.

Comment: Thank you, this works. If you want to, please post an answer, I will then accept it and update my question with an MWE.

Comment: Done, please see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand `\fromfile` before `\lstinputlisting`. One way to do so is to define a macro, say `\myInputListing`, like this:

```latex
\newcommand*{\myInputListing}[2]{%
  \lstinputlisting[style=outputstyle, #2]{#1}%
}
```

then replace `\lstinputlisting[style=outputstyle, #1]{\fromfile}` with `\expandafter\myInputListing\expandafter{\fromfile}{#1}`. Another way, assuming you are using a TeX engine from 2019 or later, would be to replace the same bit with with:

```latex
\expanded{%
  \unexpanded{\lstinputlisting[style=outputstyle, #1]}%
  \unexpanded\expandafter{\fromfile}%
}%
```

With this second solution, there is of course no need to define the `\myInputListing` macro.